# SQL Server - Creating a new login account with "sysadmin" role from an account without "sysadmin" role

Tags: sql-server-2005

My sql database has 2 accounts.

1st account is `sa`

2nd account is `user`

Both account has `sysadmin` role enabled.

We have already forgotten password for `sa`

We only know password for `user`

Somehow someone remove `sysadmin` role for `user`.

Now I need an account with `sysadmin` role.

How can I achieve that?

I cannot change the password for `sa` as some websites might be using `sa` account to connect to the database.

So, my best solution is to create a new account with `sysadmin` role by any means necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Was prodded privately to convert my comment to an answer.]

You need to enumerate the web sites that might be using sa and STOP THEM FROM DOING THAT. Then change the sa password as follows:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

You need to be a sysadmin to create a sysadmin. So instead of finding a way around the issue, which only makes your security situation even worse than it already is, fix it now and take control of your instance.