# How to add Sysadmin login to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-accounts

I have installed SQL Server 2008 using Windows Authentication in my laptop for my own use. I want to add Sysadmin account/role using SQL Server Login type. I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406247/sql-server-creating-a-new-login-account-with-sysadmin-role-from-an-account-w), but it's not showing what I need. How can I add the sysadmin account? By right shouldn't it be the default role/login?

Comment: you can create a administrator user in windows and try to install via that.All system level permissions can be granted to that windows admin

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`sysadmin` is a server role; it can be applied to any login.

When installing SQL Server a login `sa` is created with this privilege; you can specify the password when you're installing SQL Server.

Or you can create your own login:

```
CREATE LOGIN adminuser WITH PASSWORD = 'ABCDegf123';
GO

EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'adminuser', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
GO
```

[image]

This all assumes Mixed-Mode authentication is set up to allow SQL logins. [Change Server Authentication Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx).

**After comment:**

So from the link above to change to Mixed-mode in Management Studio you would:

> 1. In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties.
> 2. On the Security page, under Server authentication, select the new server authentication mode, and then click OK.
> 3. In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to acknowledge the requirement to restart SQL Server.
> 4. In Object Explorer, right-click your server, and then click Restart. If SQL Server Agent is running, it must also be restarted.

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ian, it is not configured to mixed mode initially. It is in single mode... Because when I wanted to add mixed mode there was a message saying that server will not be completeltely configured till there is a Sharepoint plugin.. ( as mixed mode needs such I reckon) so what should I do now?

Comment: SharePoint just runs on SQL Server; authentication mode is a SQL Server property independent of SharePoint so I'm not sure what's happening. Are you following the steps above? I've not seen your situation before.

Comment: +1 for your efforts. Let me try the steps and get back to you.

Comment: I was playing around and I manage to open my-computer server(which works as a server) using windows authentication and sql authentication. Both are currently running simultaneously. I am amazed. Let's say if I want restrict certain databased for certain roles under sql authentication but all are publicly accessed using win-auth, how should I go about it? :)

Comment: Well, any server-level login, Windows or SQL, can be associated with any number of database-level users. Database-level users can be associated with database roles. So you could give Windows logins read-only access to a database but full access to SQL logins. The method users use to login will determine their privilege level for that session. It's not really a question with a definite answer, it depends very much on your environment and what your security requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

'sysadmin' is a role, 'sa' is the 'system administrator' sql-login.

If you installed just using Windows Authentication (default mode), the 'sa' account is already there, but will be disabled by default. Look under *YourServerName* -> Security -> Logins in Management Studio, and you should see 'sa' with a down-arrow in the icon (symbolises a disabled user)

You have to log in using an account with sufficient privileges (if your installation account has sysadmin privileges that will work), then enable 'sa' and set a password.

Comment: I'll try out your method as well thank you. Allow me sometime to get back.