# How can I login to the SQL Server with Sysadmin privileges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, authentication

I checked this question asked before

[How to add Sysadmin login to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814798/how-to-add-sysadmin-login-to-sql-server)

I tried all the solutions mentioned but I don't have the same options 
this is the output for the first solution

[image: the output for the first solution]

and this is the menu I got for the second solution I don't have "properties" in it.

[image: the output for the second solution]

So, does anyone know how to login as a Sysadmin ?!

Comment: start->programs->sql server->right click run as admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> Open Security -> Logins 
then right click to add a new Login

or

right click on an existing Login -> Properties -> Server Roles

and give him Sysadmin rights

of course you should have enough rights yourself be allowed to do this

Answer (score 0):

if you have no SQL Server Login Mode right-click on the Server -> Server Properties -> Security and change the Server authentication method to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"

Answer (score 0):

Are you read carefully thread that you mention?

1) you must enable login of user 'sa' 
in window named Object explorer -> your DB name -> Security -> Logins -> sa
right click and check properties (last tab)

2) you must switch authentication method
in window named Object explorer -> your DB name (!not Server objects in your DB!)
right click and choose properties