# How to use Microsoft SQL Server locally?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to using SQL Server, and I have been using it at my university by connecting to the university's network. I want to be able to use SQL Server locally and have installed it on my computer.

When I am faced with the "Connect to Server" box I'm not sure what to do. I'm not sure what I should have as my server name etc. I think I have two instances installed on my computer already but I just don't know how to connect.

Even if it requires starting from scratch, creating a new instance, whatever, I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me through the steps so that I can get practising on SQL Server. I've spent hours trying to sort this out and I'm just not sure what to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to `Start > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server xxx > Configuration Tools > SQL Server xxxx Configuration Manager` (replace `xxxx` with your SQL Server version number).

You should see a screen something like this:

[image]

Look for the `SQL Server` services - I have two on my machine here.

The name in the brackets after the `SQL Server` tells you the **instance name**:

- if it's `MSSQLSERVER` (like my second line there) - it's the **default, unnamed** instance - you connect to it using `.`, `(local)`, or `machine-name` as your server / instance name
- if it's something else, that is your **instance** name - you connect to it using `.\instance-name`, `(local)\instance-name`, or `machine-name\instance-name` as your server / instance name

So in my case, to connect to the first instance, I'd use

```
.\SQLEXPRESS  
(local)\SQLEXPRESS
MyPC\SQLEXPRESS
```

as server/instance name, while the second instance can be reached by using

```
.
(local)
MyPC
```

and that's all there really is to this!

Comment: Hi. I have an SQLEXPRESS instance as well as an MSSQLSERVER instance, however neither will start. The state for both displays as 'stopped' and I get the error "request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion". I have no idea how to fix this...

Comment: @Edwards: check your Windows event log to see if there's any useful information about why those services don't start. Otherwise uninstall & reinstall

Comment: I think the problem might be that I have downloaded the wrong version, the version that I downloaded was Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express Management Studio 64-bit (English). Which download would you suggest, Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express with Tools 64-bit (English) perhaps? There are so many different ones to choose from...

Comment: @Edwards: yes - the Express with Tools would be fine. The Management Studio of course is **only** the management GUI - not the SQL Server engine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you installed a named instance or not.  If you haven't `.` or your machine name will work.  If you have setup a named instance, `.\<instance_name>` should work.

In your comment you said the instance name is SQLEXPRESS, so `.\SQLEXPRESS` should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I noticed that my instance named SQLEXPRESS is currently in the 'stopped' state. When I try to start it tells me that the "request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion". Any idea how to sort this out?

Comment: @Edwards go to your Admin Tools, Services control panel to see if its actually running or not.  If its not then start it.  If it is, you'll need to launch SSMS as an administrator and then add your workstation logon to SQL server and grant yourself the sysadmin role.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814798/how-to-add-sysadmin-login-to-sql-server

Comment: When I try to start the instance by doing that it says the system cannot find the file specified?

Comment: @Edwards did you reboot after you installed?  try that.  If you have your installation might be corrupt so I'd go to Programs and Features and try doing a repair.

Comment: Okay, I'll try rebooting, if this doesn't work what would you suggest I do?

Comment: @Edwards Did you try doing the repair in Programs and Features?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server set up to take requests over the network (even although it is only your own machine) you can use `localhost`, or the name of your machine. If not then you can use a dot `.`

If you have named the instance you'd use the format

```
.\name
```

or

```
localhost\name
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I noticed that my instance named SQLEXPRESS is currently in the 'stopped' state. When I try to start it tells me that the "request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion". Any idea how to sort this out?