# TFS 2015 Restoration failure

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, alm

I've a backup from one TFS server and I'm trying to restore it on another server.
But i'm getting this error. Please help.

> TF400998: The current user failed to retrieve the SQL Server service account information from tfssvnsvr. Please make sure you have permissions to retrieve this information.
>
> TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the instance is specified correctly, that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication with the server.

Comment: Please don't hesitate to ask any questions for more clarifications

Comment: Can you connect from SQL Manager on the TFS server to the database? Sounds like it is a firewall or other network issue... Or permissions.

Comment: Then its permissions. Does the Tfs Service account have SysAdmin on the database ?

Comment: I'm new to this, could you please tell me in detail where to look and what to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814798/how-to-add-sysadmin-login-to-sql-server

Comment: Yes I've added domain admin and tfs service account both as the admin in the sql server

Answer (score 1):

To perform [Restore Database](http://Restore%20the%20databases) procedures, you must be a member of the following groups or have the following permissions:

- A member of the **Administrators** security group on the server.
- Either a member of the **SQL Server System Administrator** security group, or your **SQL Server Perform Back Up and Create Maintenance Plan** permission must be set to **Allow**.
- A member of the **sysadmin** security group for the databases for Team Foundation.
- If the deployment uses SharePoint Products, a member of the **Farm Administrators** group for the farm to which the SharePoint Products databases are being restored.

More information of Restore a deployment to new hardware, you can refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529826(v=vs.120).aspx