# Why SQL Server Agent is not showing even after assigning sysadmin roles to user?

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, system-administration, sql-server-agent, sql-job

I am scheduling a job in SQL Server, but the SQL Server Agent is not visible in my SQL Server Management Studio and I am using version **Microsoft SQL Azure**. After creating user and assigning sysadmin roles to it, the problem still lying there.

I have created a user through **Login** under **Security** *tab* in **Object Explorer**. Assigned the ***sysadmin*** roles to that user as following through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814798/how-to-add-sysadmin-login-to-sql-server).

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'Cppa!66***', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'test', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
GO
```

I expect the result as after ***creating*** and ***assigning*** *roles*, the **SQL Server Agent** option must be visible under **Object Explorer**, but Nothing changes.

Comment: SQL Azure doesn't have SQL Agent.

Comment: You should really be using `ALTER SERVER ROLE` as well, `sp_addsrvrolemember` is deprecated and will stop working one day.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Are you sure about that?

Comment: "Azure SQL" the PaaS offering does not have SQL Agent. I am sure about that. Are you sure exactly what you are connecting to? Please run `SELECT @@VERSION` so we're all on the same page

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, I am using SQL Azure, that's why I asked you. Well thanks.

Comment: There's no product called SQL Azure. Given all the confusion, you might have been referring to SQL Server inside an Azure VM, which _does_ have SQL Agent (unless it's SQL Express). That's why it is important upfront to quote `@@VERSION`, otherwise we're all guessing. **HINT:** please edit the question and post `@@VERSION`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sorry I got confused. Yes Actually the version is:

`Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 17763: )`

Answer (score 0):

You are running SQL Express on a VM. I guess the VM happens to be on Azure. Regardless of VM location, SQL Express does not have SQL Agent.

If you want to schedule activities you can remote on to the VM and use windows scheduler.